# Двухмерные массивы. Квадратная матрица Java

Tags: java

В квадратной матрице поменять значения элементов в каждой строке, расположенные на главной и побочной диагоналях. То есть при итерации ниже необходимо вывести такую же матрицу в которой будут поменяны значения главной и побочной диагоналях.
Рандомно вывела квадратную матрицу, застряла на том как вывести в консоль еще одну матрицу в которой будут поменяны значения главной и побочной диагоналях.

Часть кода пока что выглядит так:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matrix = new int[6][6];
//цикл который будет обходить матрицу
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
//вложенный цикл
            for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = random.nextInt(101);
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
            for (int j =0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.printf("%6d", matrix[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();



        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
  int temp = matrix[i][i];
  matrix[i][i] = matrix[i][matrix[i].length - i - 1];
  matrix[i][matrix[i].length - i - 1] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо) Я правильно понимаю, данный цикл находит главную диагональ?

Comment: @novichok Нет, неправильно. Чего ее искать? `matrix[i][i]`

Comment: Спасибо) Ответ принят.

Comment: @novichok Пожалуйста. Успехов.

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1351797/%d0%a0%d0%b5%d0%b1%d1%8f%d1%82-%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%ba%d0%be-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%8e-%d0%9d%d0%b5-%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%a1%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%91%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bc-%d1%83-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be/1351837#1351837