# Ребят, только начинаю. Не ругайтесь. Суть такова: Берем у пользователя число ******* и нужно сложить между собой цифры. как сделать в цикле while?

Tags: java, массивы

```
package com.practic2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class wile {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Веди пятизначное  целое число и мы их сложим его составляющие ");
        int a = sc.nextInt();
        int b;
        while (a > 0) {
            b = a % 10;
            a = a / 10;

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Будем ругаться. Вы что, не знаете, что закорючки, из которых состоит запись *числа*, называются *цифрами*?

Comment: Число произвольное, которое вводит юзер. Или я не правильно Вас понимаю?

Comment: Понимаете неправильно. Не торопитесь. Попробуйте медленно прочитать мой комментарий. Подумайте.

Comment: ...сложить между собой цифры, из которых состоит число. Такой посыл?

Comment: Ссылка "Править" - под вопросом.

Comment: "Править"-исполнено

Comment: Ну вы же цифры уже выделяете в b, осталось сложить

Comment: Да, вы правы. Не судите строго. Не все еще операторы понимаю как будут работать и какими путями можно решить. Я смотрел в сторону массива

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int b = 0;
    while (a > 0) {
        b += a % 10;
        a = a / 10;
    }
    System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: b +=  как отрабатывает?

Comment: @apolon15 `b +=` отрабатывает очень хорошо

Comment: Да, спасибо, я проверил. Здорово. Но мне на словах как это понять? Еще не проходили, не знаю. Вот и спрашиваю . Словами как работает этот line ?

Comment: @apolon15 `b = b + ...`. `b += ...` - это укороченная запись для экономии пикселей

Comment: Спасибо большое. Оказалось все элементарно

Comment: @apolon15 Пожалуйста. Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.